# Numbers from 1 to 36 are placed in a 6 by 6 table. Consecutive numbers are in cells sharing a common side. What is the maximum sum of one diagonal?

Tags: combinatorics

I recently found this problem:

Each of the numbers from $1$ to $36$ is placed in a different square of a $6$ by $6$ table. Consecutive numbers must be placed in squares sharing a common side.

Prove that the sum of the $6$ numbers on one of the diagonals is at most $174$, and find a placement for which this maximum value is attained.

From the Taiwan 2016 IMC Selection Test: [Link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.cis.umac.mo/~fstitl/olympiad/2016%2520Taiwan%2520Selection%2520Test%2520for%2520IWYMIC.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi20s-Uj6bkAhXRLlAKHTbOAc8QFjABegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw137I3LRO-4F-P60auK6KJZ)

I'd be very grateful, if you share your ideas or solutions.

Comment: If the sum of six numbers is $174$, their average is $29$.  Also, none of the numbers on a diagonal are consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The numbers give you a non-intersecting path that covers the entire grid.   The diagonal divides the grid (and hence the path) into two equal halves, and contains no two consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, I can help with the second part -- the placement of the numbers. 
$$
\begin{matrix}
 5 &  4 &  3 &  2 &  1 & 36 \\
 6 &  7 &  8 & 33 & 34 & 35 \\
11 & 10 &  9 & 32 & 23 & 22 \\
12 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 24 & 21 \\
13 & 28 & 27 & 26 & 25 & 20 \\
14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

But this placement was obtained basing on some half-intuitive ideas, thus I'm not sure how helpful it is: I painted the table as a checkerboard thus proving that odd and even numbers should have different colors, considered placing even numbers starting from 36 on diagonal (gave me the upper bond 186), and tried to fix the "diagonal blockage" (if the diagonal is filled I can't get from one part of the table to another)